# Absolute path works when hardcoded but not when stored in variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, path, discord.py, python-os

I am trying to write a python bot that will just simply upload mass files in a directory to a server. (Mostly game clips with a few screenshots.) The issue is when I pass the file path dynamically I get a file not found error. When passing it hardcoded it works fine. I have printed and even sent to discord the file path and it is correct. Tried .strip() and .encode('unicode-escape') and various other options but haven't found anything that works. This has me a bit puzzled. Any ideas?

```
import os
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!')


#locations to upload
locations = [

        '/root/discord/',
        '/home/discord',


        ]
#file types to not upload
bad_files = [

        'viminfo',
        'txt',
        'sh',
        '',
        'bat',


        ]

#walk through directory and upload files
async def dir_walk(ctx,p):
    for roots,dirs,files in os.walk(p):
        for i in dirs:
            for x in files:
                #check to see if file extension matches one listed to not upload.
                if x.split('.')[-1] in bad_files:
                    pass
                else:
                    try:
                        #upload files
                        file_path = os.path.join(roots,i,x)
                        f = open(full_path,'rb')
                        await ctx.send(i,file = discord.File(f,filename = x))
                        time.sleep(5)
                    except:
                        raise
                        time.sleep(5)

@client.command(pass_context=True, name="walk")
async def list_dir(ctx):
     for x in locations:
     await dir_walk(ctx, x)



client.run('')
```

The traceback is :

```
Ignoring exception in command walk:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", li                                                                                        ne 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "newwalk.py", line 50, in list_dir
    await dir_walk(ctx,x)
  File "newwalk.py", line 40, in dir_walk
    f = open(x,'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ss dec_2019_1_20_0008.jpg'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", lin                                                                                        e 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", li                                                                                        ne 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", li                                                                                        ne 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Fil                                                                                        eNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ss dec_2019_1_20_0008.jpg'
```

Comment: If you could, post the error/traceback as well. Just as another codeblock or a pastebin link.

Comment: Absolutely, I completely forgot about that. I have added it now.

Comment: I have changed the code a tad but that is the same exception that it throws when I use what's shown above. only difference is when I copied the exception I was trying os.chdir(os.path.join(roots,i)) and then using f = open(x,'rb') where as before I just had the full path of the file full_path=os.path.join(roots,i,x) open(full_path,'rb')

Comment: Hm, I recommend having a `except FileNotFoundError:` block and inside of it, add every `full_path` that was not found to a list. Then print it out and see if there is something wrong. I also noticed that in `locations` the second entry doesn't end in a `/`. I doubt it is causing an error but could worth to check out. In the meantime, I am gonna do some testing and try to help figure it out

Comment: So I was able to get it to work on my bot with a weird fix. I don't know if this will work for you but essentially i split `full_path` and only used the actual file name. So after doing `full_path = os.path.join(roots,i,x)`, try `full_path = full_path.split("/")[-1]`. And then `f = open(full_path,'rb')`. If it is confusing, I can post the full code I have.

Comment: Strange, I will try that. Perhaps it's because the os.walk function is chdir into that dir?

Comment: Perhaps yeah, but to be completely honest, I am not sure why it works either. Another possible workaround could be just putting the script in the same directory as the files you want to send that way it can just work from the current working directoryHopefully someone more knowledgeable comes along and enlightens us

Comment: I was going to put it in the same directory but the file actually isn't finished. I have thousands of files organized by month & year so I am going to just have it make a channel for each year and the plan was to provide the folder and let it cycle through the rest.

Comment: I did somewhat get it to work using for item in os.listdir('.') files.append(item) and then cycle through that way.

Comment: Ah okay gotcha. Is it possible to stick all those files in a folder, and just leave the script outside the folder? That should do just fine. Ah okay nice. Yeah I am not sure how the `.split` method worked for me

Comment: I wish it was but no, we're talking tons with tons of sub folders. :(

Comment: Damn, I would recommend heading over to the discord.py and/or python discord servers and try asking there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do this. It will take some more work but I changed the code a bit. Here it is.

```
import os
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!')


#locations to upload
locations = [

        '',


        ]
#file types to not upload
good_files = [
    'png',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'mp4',
    'mpg',
    'mpeg',
    'wav',
    'flv',
    'mov',
    'gif',
    'tif',
    'bmp',




        ]

#walk through directory and upload files
async def dir_walk(ctx,p):
    for roots,dirs,files in os.walk(p):
        for i in dirs:
            os.chdir(os.path.join(roots,i))
            for x in os.listdir('.'):
                if os.path.isfile(x):
                    if x.split('.')[-1] in good_files:
                        try:
                            with open(x,'rb') as f:
                                await ctx.send(i,file = discord.File(f,filename = x))
                                time.sleep(1)
                        except:
                            pass





@client.command(pass_context=True, name="walk")
async def list_dir(ctx):
    for x in locations:
        await dir_walk(ctx,x)

client.run('')
```